# How to handle error or exception into php?

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, exception, runtime-error

I have no idea to handle error in php, both run-time and compile-time. I want to manage all types of errors.

> Notice, Warning, Parse Error, Fatal Error

When these types of errors occur, then I want my program to throw a custom written message on page. Currently I am using  `try{} catch{}`, `set_error_handler`:

```
// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

In short: I am looking for the right way to handle errors if I type wrong a variable declaration like `d` instead of `$d`, or if I forget a semi-colon in a line, or if I get a MySQL error.

Comment: What research have you done or code have you written?

Comment: @Machavity, I disagree with this being a duplicate of that - that question appears to address differences between errors and exceptions. This question asks about handling both types of problems. I'd say it _is_ related though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **both**, an error handler and an exception handler. When both, errors and uncaught exceptions are thrown you will see both messages displayed:

```
<?php
function exception_handler($exception) {
    echo "Custom exception message: " . $exception->getMessage() . "\n";
}

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo "Custom error message: "  . $errstr . "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
set_error_handler('error_handler');

//This exception will *not* cause exception_handler() to execute - 
//we have addressed this exception with catch.
try{
    throw new Exception('I will be caught!');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught an exception\n";
}

//Unmanged errors
trigger_error("I'm an error!");
throw new Exception("I'm an uncaught exception!");
?>
```

outputs:

> Caught an exception
>
> Custom error message: I'm an error!
>
> Custom exception message: I'm an uncaught exception!

You can (and should) still use `try{} ... catch(){}` to address errors as they come up, but these errors will not be handled by the exception handler after the script has finished executing.

More information about [exception handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

More information about [error handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

You want to debug your errors not suppress them. Writing code is 25% coding and 75% debugging (arguable). The reason you give to suppress errors is just bad code writing from the start.